# How to call additional method in enums?

Tags: java, enums

```
enum Enum1
{
    BIG(8), HUGE(10)
    {
        public String getName()
        {
            return "Huge";
        }

        public String getContry()
        {
            return "India";
        }//additional Method
    },
    OVERWHELMING(16)
    {
        public String getName()
        {
            return "OVERWHELMING";
        }
    };
    private int ounces;

    public int getOunes()
    {
        return ounces;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return "Ponds";
    }

    Enum1(int ounces1)
    {
        ounces = ounces1;
    }
}

class EnumAsInnerClass
{
    Enum1 enumInnerClass;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EnumAsInnerClass big = new EnumAsInnerClass();
        big.enumInnerClass = Enum1.BIG;
        EnumAsInnerClass over = new EnumAsInnerClass();
        over.enumInnerClass = Enum1.OVERWHELMING;
        EnumAsInnerClass huge = new EnumAsInnerClass();
        huge.enumInnerClass = Enum1.HUGE;
        System.out.println(big.enumInnerClass.getName());//Ponds        
        System.out.println(over.enumInnerClass.getName());//OVERWHELMING
        System.out.println(huge.enumInnerClass.getName());//Huge
    }
}
```

Consider the above example. How can I call the method getCountry for HUGE?

If there is no way to call this method, why does Java treat it as legal?

Comment: Since the entire idea of `enum` is based on the fact that all its values act in a uniform way, I don't think it's a great idea to implement a method on only a single value (or on a subset of values, generally). Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(As noted nearly 4 years later, my original answer was incorrect.)

You can't even call `Enum1.HUGE.getCountry()` with the specific enum, which is very slightly surprising... but even if you could, you couldn't do so with an arbitrary `Enum1` value, which would be more generally useful.

The solution is to stop it from being an additional method - add a `getCountry()` method into `Enum1`, either returning a default value or maybe throwing an exception. `HUGE` can then override the method.

It would be nice if you could declare that a particular enum value implemented an interface, but it seems there's no syntax for that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answere but that is not possible as it is only declared for HUGE

Comment: @ponds And that's why you can't call `getCountry()` on a `Enum1` variable, since you don't know whether you have a `HUGE` or just a `BIG`. Besides that, is there a good reason to have that method only in HUGE? Why don't you declare it in `Enum1` like Jon suggests?

Comment: Just came across this problem, that's incorrect - you can't call `HUGE.getCountry` outside the declaration of `Enum1` - see JLS section 8.9.1

Answer (score 4):

The `enum` is a type definition, similar to a class, so `Enum1` doesn't have the method `getCountry()` available in its interface.

**edit:** Alternative solution

What you *can* do is define the required methods in `Enum1` and override them in the individual enum values.

Answer (score 2):

> If there is no way to call this method then why do java treat as legal?

You can still call it within enum value definition. For example, change `getName()` function:

```
// ...
HUGE(10)
{
    public String getName()
    {
        // Call additional Method
        return "Huge" + getCountry();
    }

    public String getContry()
    {
        return "India";
    } // additional Method
},
// ...
```

Otherwise, you need to override by it to be able to call it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not suprising at all.

When you define an `enum` type (in your case `Enum1`) and declare values for it, their reference type will be of the defined type (`Enum1`). When you define methods within your `enum` declarations, you have just created **anonymous subclasses**.

```java
public enum Enum1 {

    OVERWHELMING(16) {

        public String getName() {
            return "OVERWHELMING";
        }
    };

    // And the remaining constructors, fields and methods
}
```

And you can't just *normally* call methods of an anonymous class from outside the definition itself. Likewise, `someOtherMethod()` will not be accessible from the outside either:

```java
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        someOtherMethod();
    }

    public void someOtherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Some other method!");
    }
};
```

Such methods are, however, accessible from the declaration itself, like [stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40747184/507738).

Note: Like [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) said in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959965/how-to-call-additional-method-in-enums/42090814#comment6874171_5959965), this might not be the best design. You should, for example, move your methods to the `Enum1` type.

---

There is *still* a way. It is possible to access the method through reflection:

```java
Class<?> clazz = Enum1.HUGE.getClass();
Method method = clazz.getMethod("getCountry");
System.out.println(method.invoke(Enum1.HUGE)); // Prints "India"
```